# In Wordpress, if I'm styling my own custom template, where do I put the CSS file?

Tags: wordpress

I have a child theme that I'm modifying with my own custom page, and I wanted to change the CSS on the page, but in the header of the page when I put the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />` part, I'm not sure where I should point the href to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
```

Comment: What's the value of stylesheet_url?

Comment: It's not entirely dumb, no worries. It basically just echos the location of your theme stylesheet for you automatically. Avoid absolute or relative URLs to your own domain as much as possible in favor of [site_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) and [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)